# Play Framework Scala REST DELETE

Tags: scala, playframework

I'm trying to figure out how to use the REST DELETE function using the Play Framework. Here's what I have:

My Model:

```
case class Task(id: Int, name: String, description: String, group: String)

object Task {

var list: List[Task] = Nil

def save(task: Task) = {
    list = list ::: List(task)
}

def all(): List[Task] = Nil

def delete(id: Int){
    val b = list.toBuffer
    b.remove(id)
    b.toArray
}
```

Here's what I have in my Controller for delete:

```
def deleteTask(id: Int) = Action {
    Task.delete(id)
    Ok
}
```

and my route:

`DELETE /tasks/id       controllers.TaskController.deleteTask(id: Int)`

Forgot to mention my problem! How can I run this to test and make sure that it is working? I use the command:

`curl --include 
--request POST 
--header "content-type: application/json" 
--data '{"id":4, "name": "test5", "description": "testdesc1","group": "groupc"}' http://localhost:9000/tasks`

and it posts correctly. How can I do a similar action with `DELETE`?

Comment: Your code seems to be correct. What is your specific problem?

Comment: I'm sorry, I edited my question!

Comment: Use a delete curl request?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Your DELETE request is not defined properly right now. It should go `DELETE /tasks/:id` if you want to have the `id` as a parameter

.

> The problem in your Scala code is on line `b.remove(id)` - in this case `b` is actually from type `BufferLike` and the [remove method](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.7/index.html#scala.collection.mutable.BufferLike@remove%28n:Int%29:A) does not do what you use it for. It actually removes the element at the specified `index` and not the element which you provide. So if you provide id=4 then it is going to try to remove the 5th element, and fail with an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` which is a Runtime exception which leads to the error page you are receiving.  You can just use the `diff` [method](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.7/index.html#scala.collection.mutable.BufferLike@remove%28n:Int%29:A) on List instead, like this: `val newList = list diff List(id)`

You have specified it already in your `routes` file: you have defined a `DELETE` request - this means that your curl request should also be a `DELETE` one:

```
curl -X DELETE "http://localhost:9000/tasks/4"
```

There is no body to post when using `DELETE` - you just specify the ID of the resource you would like to delete.

*Bonus:* consider returning some other status like HTTP 204 - it is more intuitive when dealing with deletion

Comment: This is not working for me. I edited the route request and tried the curl request as you instructed, but I received no error. It just returned to me HTML code of what would be the Play Framework Error Page:
http://i.imgur.com/b3b9WP8.png.

Comment: You *are* getting an error - look at the `<title>` tag in your screenshot. Execution exception is most probably a runtime error. Now try with `curl -v -X DELETE "http://localhost:9000/tasks/4"` to see the whole output and then paste it here

Comment: You don't need to examine it, the problem is actually in your Scala code: look at my edited answer